# createSheet error in R xlsx package when trying to write multiple sheets using forl oop

Tags: r, xlsx, rjava

I have 5 data frames and when I try to create a workbook with several spreadsheets all works except one . My sheet names are string. Can anyone help me in rectifying this?
All I could find is [createSheet error xlsx llibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037371/createsheet-error-xlsx-llibrary), which is not helpful in this case.

```
To_write <- c('PR1','PR2','PR3','PR4','PR5')

#Create a new workbook for ouputs
workBook <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

for(tp in To_write ){

        sheet= xlsx :: createSheet(workBook,sheetName = as.character(tp) )
        addDataFrame(Data.Trans[[tp]], sheet, startRow = 1, row.names=FALSE)

}


saveWorkbook(workBook, file=paste0( ResultDir, '/','tTest.xlsx')   )
```

Where Data.Trans is list . The error is generated only when tp <- To_write[3] and the error message is 
Error in .jcall(workBook, "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet;", "createSheet",  : 
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Please let me know what other information is required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test this:

```
Data.Trans<-list(PR1=data.frame(rnorm(100)),PR2=data.frame(rnorm(100)),PR3=data.frame(rnorm(100)),PR4=data.frame(rnorm(100)),PR5=data.frame(rnorm(100)))

To_write <- c('PR1','PR2','PR3','PR4','PR5')
library(xlsx)
#Create a new workbook for ouputs
workBook <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

for(tp in To_write ){

  sheet= xlsx :: createSheet(workBook,sheetName = as.character(tp) )
  addDataFrame(Data.Trans[[tp]], sheet, startRow = 1, row.names=FALSE)

}

dir.create("ResultDir")
saveWorkbook(workBook, file=paste0( "ResultDir", '\\','tTest.xlsx')   )
```

Comment: The error is not in dir.create, I am creating the ResultDir at the begining. The error is at sheet= xlsx :: createSheet(workBook,sheetName = as.character(tp) ) when tp = To_write[3]

Comment: @RG20: The code succeeds on my machine although it doesn't get placed in the target directory because the file name ends up with an embedded tab rather than being paced in the ResultDir. The out-of-bounds error that you are getting is not reproducible since you offered no test `Data.Trans`.

Comment: the code produces   `tTest.xlsx` in `ResultDir` successfully.

Comment: @ Are you on Windows.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. I do understand that the slashing conventions are different. I wasn't meaning that to be a criticism and I am the sole upvote so far so don't get defensive. A more cross-platform solution might be possible with `file.path` which has a platform-aware choice of directory separator.

Comment: @42- The error was generated because of an issue with my dataframe. I was able to find it only when I tried saving each df as csv. Once I rectified that issue the above code worked perfectly. In windows I use '//' or '\'. Thank you.